# "Azure AD certificate-based authentication" is not giving certificate popup

Tags: azure, authentication, certificate, x509certificate, client-certificates

I am following this document to setup "certificate based authentication" in Azure AD portal. I have made all the settings mentioned in this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/how-to-certificate-based-authentication

But the problem I am facing is: I have a user certificate installed on my windows machine, When I am trying to open Azure Portal, I am not getting any certificate pop-up. CA cert is also uploaded in the Azure portal. I think I am missing some step in certificate generation in following steps:

**Prerequisites**

Make sure that the following prerequisites are in place:

1. Configure at least one certification authority (CA) and any intermediate CAs in Azure AD.
2. The user must have access to a user certificate (issued from a trusted Public Key Infrastructure configured on the tenant) intended for client authentication to authenticate against Azure AD.

The steps that I have followed:

1. I have generated a self-signed CA certificate using following link:

   `openssl req -new -sha256 -key certAuth.key -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=MyOrg, Inc./CN=mykey" -out certAuth.csr`

   `openssl x509 -req -in certAuth.csr -CA certAuth.crt -CAkey certAuth.key -CAcreateserial -out certAuth.crt -days 500 -sha256`
2. I have uploaded only CA certificate and not intermediate CAs in Azure AD. Will it cause any issue?
3. user certificate is generated using following commands:
   https://www.golinuxcloud.com/openssl-create-client-server-certificate/#Create_client_certificate

   `1) openssl genrsa -out user1.key 4096`

   `2) openssl req -new -key user1.key -out user1.csr -subj /CN=user1@test.com`

   `3) openssl x509 -req -in user1.csr  -CA certAuth.crt -CAkey certAuth.key -out user1.crt -CAcreateserial -days 365 -sha256 -subj /CN=user1@test.com -extfile openssl.cnf`

openssl.cnf file:

```
[ req ]
default_bits       = 4096
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions     = v3_req
x509_extensions     = v3_req
[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName                 = TT
stateOrProvinceName         = TT
localityName               = TT
organizationName           = TT
commonName                 = TT
[ v3_req ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
PrincipalName   = user1@test.com
```

I can see Principal Name as subject Alternative name, Subject is user1@test.com in certificate details(when cert is installed).
There is 1 problem though: **when I installed this user cert on windows machine, I can export it's private key as well. And in other user certificates(generated by other production softwares), private key cannot be exported.**

I am not able to get a certificate pop-up with above user1 certificate. "test.com" CA certificate is self signed and installed in certificate authorities.
Am I missing something while certificate generation. There are not steps mentioned in the pre-requisites section of this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/how-to-certificate-based-authentication

Can someone please help? I need to utilize this functionality but I am not able to understand what is going wrong in certificate generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I generated the **root cert** by using below PowerShell script:

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -KeySpec Signature 
-Subject "CN=RukP2SRootCert" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable 
-HashAlgorithm sha256 -KeyLength 2048 
-CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyUsageProperty Sign -KeyUsage CertSign
```

[image]

**Now**, I exported the certificate like below:

*Go to Manage User certificates -> Personal -> Certificates -> Select your certificate -> All Tasks -> Export*

[image]

Select **`Base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER)`**:

[image]

**The certificate got exported successfully:**

[image]

For *testing*, I enabled MFA for the user and added the user in **`testrukgrp`**:

[image]

In the Azure Portal, I uploaded the certificate in Certificate authorities:

[image]

Enable the **Certificate-based authentication** and added the **`testrukgrp`**:

[image]

In configure, I made the changes like below:

[image]

Make sure to **enable the state in Registration Campaign**:

[image]

After the above config, **I am able to get the certificate popup successfully** like below:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Rukmini, can you please help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76006744/send-client-certificate-authentication-packet-to-lsalogonuser-to-get-windows-ses

Comment: accepted it. Thank you for your response. Could you please help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76006744/send-client-certificate-authentication-packet-to-lsalogonuser-to-get-windows-ses